# MySqlWorkbench DB using Xamarin does'nt .open();

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

I've made sql database using MySqlWorkbench and trying to make a connection throw Xamarin and keep getting error at the ".open();" part.

I tried making a connection in various ways I found online - none of thsoe worked.

`1`

```
    private const string SERVER= "localhost";        
    private const string DATABASE = "ReDB";
    private const string UID = "root";
    private const string PASSWORD = "root";
    private static MySqlConnection dbConnect;
    public void AddUserDB(User newUser)
    {
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Server = SERVER;
        builder.UserID = UID;
        builder.Password = PASSWORD;
        builder.Database = DATABASE;
        string connString = builder.ToString();
        dbConnect = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        string query= "INSERT INTO UserDB (...);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,dbConnect); 
        dbConnect.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnect.Close();
```

`2`

```
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    public DatabaseT1()
    {
        dbConnect = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User=root;Database=ReDB;Port=3306;Password=root");
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    }

    public void AddUserDB(User newUser)
    {
        dbConnect.Open();
        cmd.Connection = dbConnect;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserDB (...);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnect.Close();
    }
```

.

```
`Error`      
System.TypeInitializationException: <Timeout execeeded getting exception details>
```

-How can I fix this problem for good?>
Thanks :)

Comment: `localhost` would be the device|emulator itself, not the MySql host server|PC, use the IP address of the server|PC that is access-able (on the same (sub)network, ...) to the device|emulator... (BTW: I will not go into how bad of an idea it is to use a direct server-based DB connection to a mobile device, there are plenty of info floating on the Internet about this already....)

Comment: Which database way would you recommend?

Comment: use a webservice between your remote client and your db